# Store a value on PHP coming from a CLI Command Output (Windows)

Tags: php, variables, command-line-interface

I'm trying get a value (`12345678`) coming from a password vault CLI output and store this on a variable in PHP.

For example on PERL, I'm using this:

```
my $pass= qx("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CyberArk\\ApplicationPasswordSdk\\CLIPasswordSDK.exe" GetPassword /p AppDescs.AppID=SOMEAPP /p Query="Safe=SAFE;Folder=Root;Object=DATABASEX" /o Password);

chomp($pass);
```

The value of the variable `$pass` is `12345678` but I can't reproduce this on PHP, anyone can help me with that?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the exec() method to execute & get the output of a command-line execution.

```
$execResponse = exec('whoami', $output, $return_var);
echo $execResponse; // This will print the output from command line
print_r($output); // This will have the same output in an array.
```

**$command:** This parameter is used to hold the command which will be executed.

**$output:** This parameter is used to specify the array which will be filled with every line of output from the command.

**$return_var:** The $return_var parameter is present along with the output argument, then it returns the status of the executed command will be written to this variable.